# XCode UI Automation no longer working on Simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7, ios-ui-automation

I Hope someone can help me here.

I'm using XCode for UI Automation testing. For some reason, I can't run my tests on any emulators anymore. If I set the device to `Generic iOS Device` my tests appear, but once I change this to an emulator, my tests are no longer available.

I hope someone can help me. I have also tried deleting my current schemes and creating new ones, but then again, when I try to add my test folder to it, nothing is inside of it unless I select `Genetic iOS Device` first, and then the same issue occurs when I try to run my tests.

[image: When Generic Device is selected]
[image: When an emulator is selected]

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is on XCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test target has the appropriate platform and architectures. Select your project, then select the test target. Under Build Settings, make sure Architectures is set to Standard and Supported Platforms to iOS (which should be iphonesimulator and iphoneos).